# How to keep some text non editable and some editable in textview swift?

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have one textview i am want to keep some text non-editable and other text editable.
FOr ex. My textview has text "My name is: Sandesh Sardar". so my name is should non editable and other text should editable. is there any method to do this in Swift 5?

Is this possible using textrange. means if I have big non editable text?
also is there any better way if i have multipe such textview?

OR how can we stop editing after certain range in textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this piece of code to get your result. It means `textView` would not return `true` while editing, if the existing text is `My name is:`. For example, if you want to stop after user has entered around 30 characters make a check inside like below.

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if let textViewText = textView.text {
            if textViewText == "My name is:" && text == "" {
                return false
            }

            //For text range
            if let textRange = Range(range, in: textViewText) {
                let updatedText = textViewText.replacingCharacters(in: textRange,
                                                                   with: text)
                return updatedText.count < 30 + 11 //11 characters for *My name is:*
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice answer, can you please suggest how to check same using text range..because I have multiple textview with same logic?

Comment: You are welcome. Are you asking about text range by excluding _My name is:_ string or including that as well? Please update your question so I can make a change accordingly, @SandeshSardar.

Comment: Check the edited answer, with **//For text range** tag.